# how to capture only SMTP using latest Wireshark 2.2.6 or later

Tags: tcp, internet, wireshark, troubleshooting

I am debugging a problem with my Azure VM Windows server receiving SMTP from the Internet, and want to use Wireshark to show ONLY SMTP.
I would also like to use Wireshark to show the contents of the SMTP message to see if it is what I sent.

I cannot figure out, nor find help, on just simply making Wireshark show only SMTP.  Wireshark doc says to set filter to SMTP, but that does not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure it is using SMTP and not SMTPS? Most SMTP traffic is now utilizing SMTPS since it is encrypted. With SMARTTLS, SMTPS can use port TCP/25, but check on ports TCP/587 or possibly TCP/465 for SMTPS traffic.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering while capturing data in Wireshark is documented here: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

An example of such for SMTP is: `tcp port smtp`

Filtering already captured data is here:
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDisplayFilterSection.html

An example of such for SMTP is: `tcp.port == 25` or simply `smtp`

When configuring display filters, you have to make sure to press <kbd>enter</kbd> or click `Apply`